# Can I group multiple components inside a package in UML Diagrams?

Tags: design-patterns, module, architecture, uml

I need to split a monolithic application into sub modules, there are certain modules like util, exceptions, dto etc which can be clubbed in one module i.e. commom.
Service, DAO, Controller will be separate modules.

How do I achieve this.

Can I have a Common package with util, exception, dto, domain components in them and then have DAO, Controller, Service as separate components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's in general the role of packages.

You can make a package Common and then include subpackages (util, exceptions, dto etc.) in it. Then you can have separate packages like Service, DAO and Controller.

Comment: I thought uitl and common code with no dependencies goes inside Common and DAO, SERVICE, CONTROLLER would be outside the common as separate packages.

Comment: sorry, I copied the wrong part of your answer :-) Fixed now.